# MooTools: Get the first and last days of a given week

Tags: javascript, date, mootools, weekday

I'm relatively inexperienced in JavaScript (we're using MooTools, here) and I'm stuck with a problem:

Is there a quick way to get the first and last dates of a given week? 
e.g. week 17 / 2015 starts on Monday, April 20th and ends on Sunday, April 26th.

My goal is to find out if a given week starts and ends in the same month (week 18 wont, since it starts on April 27th and ends on May 3rd).

Many thanks on any help with examples or pointing me to the right documentation. 
I've been looking for a while and haven't found anything like this, and I find MooTools documentation very poor...

Comment: MooTools offers an easy way to know what week a given day is part of (`Date.get('week')`), but no obvious way of getting the terminal dates of a given week.

Comment: I guess I'll manage this by creating hidden fields in PHP with starting and ending dates for each week, and then get those values with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite Filipe,

to do this you do not need MooTools. You can do with Vanilla JS.

Here is an idea:

```
function dayAnalizer(str) {
    var date = new Date(str).getTime();
    var weekAfter = date + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return new Date(date).getMonth() == new Date(weekAfter).getMonth();
}

console.log(dayAnalizer('10-05-2015')); // true
console.log(dayAnalizer('13-05-2015')); // false
console.log(dayAnalizer('16-05-2015')); // false
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1g4bvgjg/

basically it gets a date in string format and converts it to timestamp (miliseconds), then create another date 1 week forward. In the end compare if both have same month.

If you need to know if a certain week in a year starts and ends in the same month you could use something like this:

```
function weekAnalyser(week, year) {
    var days = (1 + (week - 1) * 7); // 1st of January + 7 days for each week
    var date = new Date(year, 0, days);
    var dayOfWeek = date.getDay(); // get week day
    var firstDayOfWeek = date.getTime() - (dayOfWeek) * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000); // rewind to 1st day of week
    var endOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek + 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return new Date(firstDayOfWeek).getMonth() == new Date(endOfWeek).getMonth();
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zfassz29/

---

Ps. Welcome to Portuguese Stackoverflow: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: This doesn't quite match the OP's question, however. This tests whether 'date' and 'date + 1 week' are in the same month. But that's not the same as testing whether Week 32 of 2014 crosses a month boundary. (Which is complicated for a number of reasons, including the proper definition of the first day of a week being locale-dependent)

Comment: @SMcCrohan very right. I read the question too fast. Edited and added that functionality so the OP can adapt.

Comment: Thanks @Sergio, your weekAnalyser function is working fine.
I'll have to toon it up, thou, since it seams that it is assuming first day of week as being sundays (it gets week 23/2015 as being on two months, since week 23/2015 starts on monday, june 1st, it should return true).

Comment: @FilipeCastanheira yeah, here in Sweden week starts on sunday :) But you are right, in PT its monday and I should know that :P